# Java Security Framework with OAuth

Tags: java, security, oauth, spring-security, shiro

Can anyone recommend a Java Security Framework that supports authentication with OAuth and OAuth so that we can offer integration with the likes of Google/Twitter/Facebook etc. as well as other security features such as cryptography, password reset, security questions etc.  I've looked at Apache Shiro which looks good but doesn't seem to have the Social side of things covered.  I've also investigated Spring Security which seems to cover as lot of areas but I'm not sure whether you need to be using Spring MVC to use this (we're using Wicket + Spring for the service layer).

Any recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security covers all the areas you need (the social stuff is called [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social), you can have a look at it).

Also *no* you don't need to be using Spring MVC. Any web framework can use Spring Security.

Comment: ask a more specific question if you need to

Answer (score 0):

Check Oracle Fusion Middleware (Oracle ADF 11g.)